# Is there any 'Search Software Center' lens?

Tags: 12.04, lenses

in 12.04 i have noted that there is a lens for almost everything, so i was wondering if there is any such lens to search USC and GetDeb, I also wanted to know if there is a lens to search Custom Website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'apps available for download' section in the dash when you press super-A is essentially a search USC lens. Is that what you're looking for or have I misunderstood?

Comment: no, youre right, i hadnt noticed that